# How to detect touch annotation view event?

Tags: xcode

I have some Annotationview on map. I just wanna detect event that happen when user touch it.
I figure out using observer, I add observer for each annotationview in viewForAnnotation delegate method. I thought it would work perfect, but something still wrong. "selected" attribute of annotationview change its value unexpectedly. 
Someone tell me how to solve this problem. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You should see about the MKMapViewDelegate there is this method to implement in order to do that :

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

See the apple's doc
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add event handler to your custom annotation view:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

You can also use KVO as this [method](http://www.zenbrains.com/blog/en/2010/05/detectar-cuando-se-selecciona-una-anotacion-mkannotation-en-mapa-mkmapview/).